# Ansible: module command

Tags: ansible

I want to execute this command with Ansible:

```
grep -v -P "^#" /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map > /etc/snort/community-sid-msg-no-comments.map
```

I want to know what characters I have to include in my Ansible code:

```
- name: create file
  command: "grep -v -P "^#" /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map > /etc/snort/community-sid-msg-no-comments.map"
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, your question is not clear... Can you please clarify?

Comment: One thing to check may be to use single quotes for the `^#` part: `"grep -v -P '^#' ..."`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better to use the *copy* and *replace* modules?

```
- copy:
    src: /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map
    dest: etc/snort/community-sid-msg-no-comments.map
- replace:
    path: etc/snort/community-sid-msg-no-comments.map
    regexp: "^#[^\n]*\n"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will do so.